# How do I do Python typing against an internationalized API output?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing

I am writing a module that integrates with an API that internationalizes it output.

If a client is using English I may get:

```
{
    vehicle: {
        model: …,
        …
    },
   …
}
```

But a German client would get:

```
{
    fahrzeug: {
        modell: …,
        …
    },
   …
}
```

How would I set up Python typing in such a way that I don’t have to write a new type for every supported language?

```
update_vehicles(vehicles: Sequence[Vehicle]) -> Sequence[Vehicle]:
    …
```

Comment: Sounds like you are using [`TypedDict`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0589/)?  Because the regular `Dict` and `Mapping` type hints don't care about the *values* of the keys, just the *types* of the keys.

Comment: You should convert them to something canonical at the edge of your program, otherwise you're going to have conditional logic all over the place.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I’m not doing much logic in my module, but I want to make it such that someone digesting the data from an internationalized version would have an appropriate type available.